# How to run a command without hitting Enter Key?

Tags: shell, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts

Accidently I mapped <kbd>Enter</kbd> via `xkbset` to `Pointer_button2`.

Now every time I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> some gibberish text appears.

I thought of a workaround involving remapping it back, but that means I will have to run a command `xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Pointer_Button2"` (or any other keycode but that of <kbd>Enter</kbd>). But I'm not able to run this command in terminal, without hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

How do I do so?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: One day computers will be able to undo anything.  Like we have with file system snapshots now, but with the contents of RAM... like rolling back what we are doing.  Un-enter a command.  Un-open a file.  Un-run a program.  Un-Do last 5 minutes.  Then, later the internet will catch up ... Un-read a web-site:  You were never there!  Maybe one day we will be able to un-do motor car accidents, restore the lamp posts to upright, etc.

Comment: @Johan What kind of substances did you take when you wrote this comment ? </kidding>

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> as an alternative to <kbd>Enter</kbd>. They are the control characters for linefeed (LF) and carriage return (CR).

Comment: Sheesh… why can't folks with 6,705 points let some of these easy questions through to the vast unwashed masses to answer? (Just kidding -- +1 for the answer I was going to post.)

Comment: @JanSteinman Because then they would only have 6,330 points (6705 - 15 - 36*10). :P

Comment: @JanSteinman: I did let it through! There were already three other answers when I answered, and one was accepted. It seems kids these days don't know their ASCII :-) (@ernie: there's a daily reputation cap, so you don't get all those points).

Comment: Thanks for accepting some good-natured ribbing -- no slight intended at all. If you know it, show it!

Comment: @JanSteinman and camh, are there any historical reasons behind this convention (Enter ~= Ctrl+M/J)?

Comment: @user13107 Not so much historical as just the ASCII code definition itself.  When ASCII was pretty much all there was (unless you were in IBM land) the Return and Linefeed keys had to be coded as something so we could type them on our trusty ASR-33 teletypes or our punch cards.  There's even an ascii package you can install that will display it.  The Ctrl key just took the code for one of the first 32 characters and set one bit back to 0.  For M, it changed a 4D to a 0D which is a carriage return (and there really was a carriage on an ASR-33.)

Comment: @Joe But ASR-33 already had return and linefeed keys right? Hence, are you sure that the reason for `^-J` `^-M` being interpreted as Enter really this?

Comment: @Utku - They had those keys, but they only had 8 bits to play with and one of them was for rubouts - so characters on the paper tapes could be "erased". With 7 bits, things got pretty squashed together. Another was the difference between lower and uppercase. Another was for Ctrl. That left just 6 bits to get everything else done. So the Return key really just sent the same code as Ctrl+M and the Linefeed key just sent Ctrl-J. It was an artifact of the hardware/coding limitations. It was amazing how much they squeezed out of that little!

Comment: @Utku - Later, when paper tape went away, that bit was freed up and we got non-standard extended ASCII codes so you could put a heart or a club on the screen or a line drawing character. That was a big deal back then. It's hard to imagine now. My previous comment isn't precisely correct, but it's close.

Answer (score 26):

Run the command from a non-X terminal.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> should get you to a normal console.  Login as your normal user, and then run the command there.

`xmodmap` only affects X sessions so it needs `DISPLAY` to work outside the X server, like this:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xmodmap
```

Comment: Thanks. But it gives error that `xmodmap unable to open display \`\``

Comment: You can give it a display with `DISPLAY="0"`, or edit the file, should be in `$HOME/.Xmodmap`

Comment: Small typo: `DISPLAY=:0`

Answer (score 14):

You could put it into a script (.sh) and then double click it. Most modern desktop environments give the option of running a script instead of opening it in a text file.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. Didn't find the option of running it as a script.

Comment: Ok. It works after changing the file properties.

Answer (score 12):

If you have a mouse and graphical display you can copy the end of a previous line in your terminal and paste it onto the end of your command.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is another option. With bash it executes the command and moves to the next most recent in history, it is useful to cycle back through a chain of previously executed commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a mouse then just copy this -> "

"

and paste next to your command and then paste entire command in the terminal.

**Like 
[image]**

Comment: This has already been given as an answer